# VARCHAR truncated to 25 characters when saved through model

Tags: database, mysql, model

Given mysql column is created under a table after extension installation. As mentioned, the size of VARCHAR column is 100.

```
$table_config->addColumn(
'value',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
100,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
```

);

But when I try to save a created API key through model->save() method. The string gets truncated to 25 characters only.

```
$key = hash('sha256', 'mm_'.rand());
/save API Key in the configure page
    Mage::getModel('mm_sync/config')->setData(array(
            'name'  => 'api/key',
            'value' => $key,
        ))
        ->save();
```

The same value in the table:

```
+-----------+---------+--------------------------+
| config_id | name    | value                    |
+-----------+---------+--------------------------+
|         1 | api/key | 91XVVbiUBMDt40jZgKA51g== |
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take them step by step

```
$key = hash('sha256', 'mm_'.rand());
```

this line is useless, because the value of `$key` is overwritten on the line below:

```
$key = substr(Mage::helper('core')->encrypt('mm_'.rand()), 0, 49);
```

this means that `$key` will contain the first 49 chars of the result of: `Mage::helper('core')->encrypt('mm_'.rand());`

If you look int the method `Mage_Core_Helper_Data::encrypt` you will see something like this:

```
public function encrypt($data)
{
    if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
        return $data;
    }
    return $this->getEncryptor()->encrypt($data);
}
```

Assuming you are on community edition `$this->getEncryptor()->encrypt($data)` translates to `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption::encrypt($data)`.  This method looks like this:

```
public function encrypt($data)
{
    return base64_encode($this->_getCrypt()->encrypt((string)$data));
}
```

this means you should end up with a base64 encoded string. And the one you posted looks like one to me.  the length of the generated string can be anything.

Comment: Apologies. One of the testing lines got left under the code snippet. But yes, you identified the problem. Thanks

Comment: Awesome track down of the problem, @Marius :)